# How to inherit vocabulary in Bixby in a concept used in NL

Tags: bixby

I have a concept which has an enum and a vocab. When I inherit this concept in another concept and use in training, the NL fails (but aligned NL works). If I change the vocab to be for the inherited concept, then the NL works.

I would like a single enum concept which has vocab and two child concepts which inherit both the enum and training - the Capsule is for a train schedule so the departure and arrival station use the same vocab and enum

Answer (score 1):

If you extend a type into another capsule, a new vocabulary file must still be created. Vocabulary is never inherited, even if you use extends or add role-of to a model.

You most likely need to use role assignments as described [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training#add-context-with-roles) in the dev docs. This way you can provide Bixby with more context to discern between a departure and arrival station while using the same vocab and enum.